# British Airways Luggage Allowance

Tags: luggage, london, british-airways

i am travelling on club world from Singapore to London and i understand from their site that the maximum check in luggage is two items at 32kg each. As i am relocating to the country, i currently have more than 2 luggage but total weight should not exceed 64kg. Do you know if BA is strict on the 2 luggage policy and that i have to purchase additional luggage allowance regardless?

Answer (score 4):

You can increase your luggage allowance now in advance, by buying additional bags through Manage My Booking on ba.com. (If you have a ticket issued by a travel agent you may have to go back to the agent to discuss this, but for most tickets it will work fine.) Buying additional pieces online is cheaper than doing it at the airport.

At time of writing, [the price is £120/US$180/€140 for each additional bag online, or £140/US$200/€150 at the airport](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/modalContent/information/baggage-essentials/extra-and-overweight-baggage/current-longhaul-premium.html).

Each additional bag you purchase can also weigh up to 32 kg.

As Berwyn says, if you hold Oneworld Emerald status through top tier status in any oneworld airline, then you will be entitled to one additional 32 kg bag for free (*i.e.*, you would receive three free bags).

If you are intending to take more than nine pieces you may have to contact British Airways directly by telephone because of a systems limitation.

Comment: The 3 bags for Silver/Sapphire has gone. Has it come back?

Comment: @Berwyn Sorry, you are correct. Only emeralds get an "additional" bag. Didn't notice that enhancement.

Comment: I think you are mixing up OneWorld Emerald and Sapphire. Both Sapphire and Emerald get *one* additional bag over the CW total (i.e. 3): https://www.oneworld.com/ffp/sapphire-privileges and https://www.oneworld.com/ffp/emerald-privileges. I did this myself recently (I am Sapphire), so I know it works.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier "On international or domestic itineraries using the baggage allowance "piece" system - one additional bag*, weighing up to 23 kgs, up to a maximum of two pieces."

Comment: Duh. Ok, it would help if I read it more carefully :) Thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

BA provides a free third bag in CW only for people with BA Gold/OneWorld Emerald status. Given that this is a benefit for people with that status level, I rate your chances of an extra bag as roughly zero if you don't have that status.

It's worth noting that you can carry two items of hand luggage weighing up to 23kg each on board providing you adhere to the [size limits](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/changes-to-our-baggage-allowances). It's unlikely that your hand luggage will be weighed or measured providing it's not too obviously extreme.

Comment: Hand luggage 23 kg each?  That's impressive.

Comment: _You_ might be able to carry two 23-kilo bags. Pretty sure I couldn't! :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby  s/can/are allowed/ ;)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Wheeled bags make it a lot easier.  Since you can normally avoid having to lift more than 1 bag at a time, and rolling them requires far less force than carrying.

Comment: I once carried a 32kg box about 400 meters. I hope to never do that again.

Answer (score 2):

If you come with 5 pieces, yes it will be an issue. If you have 3 and you are loyal customer for them (with a status), then you have a good probability to be able to check-in all your luggage without any issue. If you ask me for a percentage, I would say 30-40%. They might also ask you to pay for something extra.

Comment: Why would five pieces be an issue? If you are not entitled to five pieces, you just pay the appropriate extra bag fees. What is this a percentage of?

Comment: Five will definitely not make it for free... 30-40% is the probability of not being charged extra for the 3rd piece.

Comment: Oh I see. I agree that three additional free bags won't happen. I think the fees are now pretty strictly enforced.

Comment: @Calchas - Not strictly enforced... Last month I helped my wife check in for a BA flight from JFK and the agent had a sense of humor.  I laughed at his jokes, played along with his suggestion of being my wife's bodyguard, and he didn't charge us for her very excess baggage...

Comment: If you can still fit everything in two bags (going over the weight restriction) I would recommend this over a third bag. They are much more likely to charge you for the extra bag than they are to charge you for being overweight. I've frequently gotten away without having to pay extra for heavy bags, they just put a "heavy" sticker on them and carry on as if everything is normal. Comping extra bags is more likely to be noticed by other passengers waiting in line; I think the chances of them doing this for you are slimmer. Worse case they charge the overweight fee, which I think is less anyway.

Comment: @KevinRubin Was it excess in weight or in number?

Comment: @JoeMalpass OP is asking about business class, though. They tend to be a bit more lenient there and they usually have separate check-in lines.

Comment: Thanks guys for the fast responses! Seems like i have got to purchase additional luggage then online. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I thought I should mention luggage allowances are higher for nearly all international flights to & from the US (& Canada).

Comment: Do you have a reference? I'm asking because practically all airlines are moving in the other direction (less free luggage), so some kind of 'proof' would be welcome.